# Как вывести путь между вершинами, полученный с помощью алгоритма Дейкстры (в алгоритме Джонсона)?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, графы

Работаю над программой, которая находит кратчайшие пути между вершинами взвешенного ориентированного графа с помощью алгоритма Джонсона,в котором, собственно, и используется алгоритм Дейкстры. После того, как в графе с ребрами отрицательных весов, были изменены веса, к каждой вершине применяется алгоритм Дейкстры. Вот сама функция:

```
SingleSP djikstra(const Graph& g, int s)
{
    SingleSP dist(g.size(), INF);
    set<pair<int,long>> frontier;

    frontier.insert({0,s});

    while (!frontier.empty())
    {
        pair<int,long> p = *frontier.begin();
        frontier.erase(frontier.begin());

        int d = p.first;
        int n = p.second;

        dist[n] = d;

        for (auto e : g[n])
        {
            if (dist[n]+e.cost < dist[e.head])
            {
                if (dist[e.head] != INF)
                    frontier.erase(frontier.find({dist[e.head], e.head}));
                frontier.insert({dist[n]+e.cost, e.head});
                dist[e.head] = dist[n]+e.cost;
            }
        }
    }

    return dist;
}
```

С помощью этой функции находится кратчайший путь между двумя вершинами, но так как функция вызывается несколько раз, мы находим необходимое число расстояний. Вот вызов функции:

```
AllSP allsp(g.size());
    for (int i = 1; i < g.size(); i++)
    {
        allsp[i] = djikstra(g, i);
    }
```

Здесь используется:

```
    struct Edge
        {
          int head;
          long cost;
        };

    using Graph = vector<vector<Edge>>;
    using SingleSP = vector<long>;
    using AllSP = vector<vector<long>>;
    const long INF = LONG_MAX;
```

Хочу создать матрицу, в которой будут хранится списки вершин, через которые были найдены кратчайшие пути для каждой пары вершин, но пока не понимаю, как это сделать (хотя уже читала соответствующий материал). Вывод самих вершин планирую реализовать в другой функции.
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, как это лучше всего сделать.

P.S. Программа не моя, исходник брала на GitHub: https://gist.github.com/ashleyholman/6793360/ae69b92bad8d5ba6bf0383efcd92a2e6b8760ab0 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если после отработки алгоритма Дейкстры у вас сохранился полученный в процессе его работы массив `dist[]` (а все эти массивы у вас сохраняются в `allsp`), то восстановить по нему кратчайший путь несложно: в вершину `n` вы пришли из той соседней вершины `m`, для которой выполняется

```
dist[n] = dist[m] + e.cost;
```

где `e` - это ребро из `m` в `n`. Если таких `m` окажется несколько, то можно брать любую из них.

Так что если вы хотите построить кратчайший путь между вершинами `u` и `v`, то вам надо взять ваш массив `allsp[u]` и в нем, начиная с вершины `v` отступать по одному шажку назад (вышеописанным способом), пока вы не доберетесь до `u`. (Или наоборот, взять массив `allsp[v]` и в нем отступать от `u` до `v`.)

---

На самом деле, если вам нужна такая информация, то ее можно было сохранить еще в процессе работы алгоритма Дейкстры. Кратчайший путь в вершину `n` проходит через ту соседнюю вершину `m`, из которой вершина `n` получила свою последнюю (т.е. минимальную) пометку `dist[n]`.